# Is there any normal help in nowadays MS Office?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-onenote-2010, help-files

I found that Office 2010 does not contain normal help system. For example, being in OneNote 2010 I am unable to find how to enter mathematical formulas and which latext codes are supported. Neither help request brought result.

So, the question is: should it work at all?

Comment: The online help that Office 2010 has does have a table of contents. Microsoft went to the new help system with the 2007-2008 product line. The old help files are formats not used by Microsoft.

Comment: So, how would you learn from new help system, that you can enter `^` to make upper index and `_` to make lower when entering math?

Answer (score 1):

The help dialog in MS Office is mostly based around searching (see that searchbox?) now, and it usually works well.

---

If you want to view supported ... LaTeX codes ... click `File` > `Options`, go to `Proofing` and then `AutoCorrect Options`. They're listed in the `Math AutoCorrect` tab.

[[image: Screenshot of AutoCorrect options]
<sup>Click for full size</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIAUw.png)

There's also a partial list [here](http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=474856)

Comment: So, no latex is supported in fact? Only symbol entities? How would I know, that underscore codes lower index and caret codes upper one?